# react-google-maps project on AWS

Tags: reactjs

When deploying reactJS project from github to aws I have following error:

Error: Cannot find module 'react-google-maps'

Does anyone knows how to resolve this problem? 
On local host everything is perfect, bu that's might because I manually installed google-react-maps, os I can I canfigure the same for AWS?

Answer (score -1):

After deploying from github you should install depedencies of project.
Run terminal, go to project folder, then type command:

```
npm install
```

Comment: Thx, do you mind to give a bit more details? I'm completely newbie.
I created new instance in Code Pipline using Elastic Beanstalk and do not completely understand how can I launch treminal in AWS.